# Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ..." after upgrade babel-plugin-react-css-modules

Tags: webpack, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I have started to get the error since upgrade babel-plugin-react-css-modules from 2.8.0 to 3.3.2:

```
> node ./server.js

Listening at ipmc-dev11.be-md.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov:3000
Hash: a9c93503d372d94f4710
Version: webpack 3.8.1
Time: 2752ms
                           Asset    Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    main-a9c93503d372d94f4710.js  575 kB       0  main
main-a9c93503d372d94f4710.js.map  703 kB       0  main
  [19] (webpack)/hot/log.js 1 kB {0} [built]
  [29] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75 bytes {0} [built]
  [57] multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://ipmc-dev11.be-md.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov:3000 webpack/hot/only-dev-server react-hot-loader/patch ./assets/index 64 bytes {0} [built]
  [58] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://ipmc-dev11.be-md.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov:3000 7.95 kB {0} [built]
  [59] ./node_modules/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
  [65] ./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
  [67] ./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 7.74 kB {0} [built]
  [68] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 kB {0} [built]
  [70] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.73 kB {0} [built]
  [75] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {0} [built]
  [77] (webpack)/hot/only-dev-server.js 2.3 kB {0} [built]
  [78] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.27 kB {0} [built]
  [79] ./node_modules/react-hot-loader/patch.js 41 bytes {0} [built]
  [80] ./node_modules/react-hot-loader/lib/patch.js 209 bytes {0} [built]
 [197] ./assets/index.jsx 617 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
    + 183 hidden modules

ERROR in ./assets/index.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shifrinb2/submission_ui/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-css-modules/dist/index.js:37:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://ipmc-dev11.be-md.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov:3000 webpack/hot/only-dev-server react-hot-loader/patch ./assets/index
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

babel-plugin-react-css-modules is configured to use babel-loader, web pack config:

`module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(pretty-bytes|babel-plugin-react-css-modules))/,
                use: [{loader: 'babel-loader'}],
            },`

Do I need to adjust something else to get working the new version?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in version of node, upgrade to 6.10.3 have solved the issue